# OneToOneField with ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following situation:

```
class Professor(models.Model):
    default_address = models.OneToOneField('Address')

class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    street_address = models.CharField()
    # ...
    professor = models.ForeignKey("Professor", related_name="addresses")
```

Basically, one `Professor` can have many `Address`es associated with it, but only one `default_address` selected. However, things aren't working right when I save things with my view, things don't get associated just right:

```
form = forms.ProfileEditForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    address = professor.default_address or models.Address()
    address.name = "Default" if address.name == None else address.name
    address.street_address = form.cleaned_data['street_address']
    address.street_address_2 = form.cleaned_data['street_address_2']
    # ...
    address.save()

    professor.default_addresss = address
    professor.save()
```

After I save it, `professor.default_address` is `None`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set `user_profile` on both the `Address` and the `PhoneNumber` before saving:

```
address.user_profile = user.profile
address.save()

phone_number.user_profile = user.profile
phone_number.save()

user.profile.default_address = address
user.profile.default_phone_number = phone_number
user.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code:

```
professor.default_addresss = address
```

Should be

```
professor.default_address = address
```

Basically, nothing happens on `save()` for non model attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making the address "default" if no name is supplied. If that's the case, why not just get rid of the One-To-One field and simply create an instance method on the Professor model that gets you the address with the name of "default."

Or, you could create a boolean field on the Address model called `is_default` (or something along those lines) and make that True if no name is supplied.